# NameError: uninitialized constant CarrierWave::Storage::Fog in Heroku Logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, amazon-s3

Hello i just added AWS S3 Bucket to my app.

Here is the app error https://dry-atoll-6663.herokuapp.com/

In heroku logs when i $heroku restart this error appears

```
2015-04-28T09:13:15.009823+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] ! Unable to load application: NameError: uninitialized constant CarrierWave::Storage::Fog
```

My Carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
config.fog_credentials = {
  # Configuration for Amazon S3
  :provider              => 'AWS',
  :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
  :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY']
}
config.fog_directory     =  ENV['S3_BUCKET']
end
```

Any ideas? Me and my friend are scratching our heads big time...

Comment: actually where you created this carrierwave.rb file?

Comment: Also you can check some demo applications like https://github.com/trevorturk/carrierwave-heroku and also take a look into this http://qiita.com/kimihito_/items/3ff9c0c4407447ee3ab3

Comment: I see that you're loading your S3 keys from environment variables. Have you ensured that you set those environment variables on Heroku? Also, did you get any errors when you deployed your app? Maybe CarrierWave wasn't successfully installed during deploy or something?

Comment: may be it's a stupid question but do you have `gem 'fog'` in your Gemfile?

Comment: I just did an update of the carrierwave gem and it seems like they have updated the required information in the config: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#using-amazon-s3 It gave me the same error message and updating the config solved it.

Comment: Yes the update fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

Credit @Marcus for correctly answering this in the comments.

In your `config/initializers/carrierwave.rb` file, you will need to update

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  # This is the old way, and broken
  config.storage = :fog
```

into

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  # This is the new way!
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'
```

see [the carrierwave github](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#using-amazon-s3) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

After pulling my hair out for a couple hours, I finally determined that this seems to come from a recent [issue with `carrierwave (0.10.0)`](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1698)

With thanks to GitHub user [trantorLiu](https://github.com/trantorLiu), this is what fixed me up:

> I also encountered this issue. I fixed it by specify an older
>   Carrierwave revision in *Gemfile.lock*.
>
> Here's my Gemfile.lock. Revision `37cf31d` doesn't work for me, so I
>   rollbacked to `cb1a5bf`. And then everything worked as it used to be.
>
> ```
> GIT
>   remote: git://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave.git
>   revision: cb1a5bfc6601a4e5d0abb6bad17911d73dcb57e3
>   specs:
>     carrierwave (0.10.0)
>       activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
>       activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
>       json (>= 1.7)
>       mime-types (>= 1.16)
> ```
>
> Here's my Gemfile. FYI.
>
> ```
> gem 'fog', require: 'fog/aws'
> gem 'carrierwave', github: 'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'
> ```

Also, if it helps, here my `config/initializers/carrierwave.rb`:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  if Rails.env.development?
    config.storage = :file
  elsif Rails.env.test?
    config.storage = :file
    config.enable_processing = false
  else
    config.storage = :fog
    config.fog_credentials = {
      provider:               'AWS',
      aws_access_key_id:      Rails.configuration.aws.access_key_id,
      aws_secret_access_key:  Rails.configuration.aws.secret_access_key,
    }
    config.fog_directory  = Rails.configuration.files.aws_bucket
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Upon further review, I decided to drop `fog` altogether. I ended up using [`carrierwave-aws`](https://github.com/sorentwo/carrierwave-aws). The config is practically identical.

My new `config/initializers/carrierwave.rb`:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  if Rails.env.development?
    config.storage = :file
  elsif Rails.env.test?
    config.storage = :file
    config.enable_processing = false
  else
    config.storage = :aws
    config.aws_bucket = Rails.configuration.files.aws_bucket
    config.aws_acl = 'public-read'
    config.aws_credentials = {
      access_key_id: Rails.configuration.aws.access_key_id,
      secret_access_key: Rails.configuration.aws.secret_access_key,
      region: Rails.configuration.aws.region,
    }
  end
end
```